# AMDGPU CPU Query Frequency

Tags: cpu, amd-graphics, cpu-frequency, amd

on most CPU you can use "cpufreq-aperf" to check cpu frequency, but I don't think this is compatible with AMDGPU.

I did check for "aperf" and found:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -o "aperf[a-z]*" | head -1
aperfmperf
```

Attempt to use "cpufreq-aperf":

```
$ sudo cpufreq-aperf
Error reading /dev/cpu/0/msr, load/enable msr.ko

$ sudo modprobe msr

$ sudo cpufreq-aperf
CPU Average freq(KHz)   Time in C0  Time in Cx  C0 percentage
000 [offline]
001 [offline]
002 [offline]
003 [offline]
```

Am I missing something, or is this tool incompatible with AMDGPU? (I have an A10-8700P). The fact that "msr" is not autoloaded makes me thing it's not compatible.

So is there another tool I can use, or am I missing something?

Reason I want this, is i've enabled powerplay and I'd like someway to see the effect (other than running benchmarks).

Update, I think it maybe related to a module I have loaded that I may need to remove?

These are my modules;

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ac                     16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  67520
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
ahci                   36864  3
amdgpu               1327104  3
amdkfd                122880  1
arc4                   16384  2
autofs4                36864  2
battery                16384  0
binfmt_misc            20480  1
button                 16384  0
ccm                    20480  2
cfg80211              471040  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
crc16                  16384  1 ext4
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
cryptd                 20480  22508 ablk_helper,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
ctr                    16384  4
drm                   286720  7 amdgpu,ttm,drm_kms_helper
drm_kms_helper        122880  1 amdgpu
ecb                    16384  2
ecryptfs               90112  1
efi_pstore             16384  0
efivarfs               16384  1
efivars                20480  1 efi_pstore
ehci_hcd               77824  1 ehci_pci
ehci_pci               16384  0
evdev                  24576  17
ext4                  499712  1
fam15h_power           16384  0
fat                    65536  1 vfat
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
hid                   106496  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
hid_generic            16384  0
hp_accel               28672  0
hp_wireless            16384  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
i2c_core               53248  8 i2c_hid,i2c_piix4,i2c_designware_core,i2c_algo_bit,amdgpu,i2c_designware_platform,drm_kms_helper,drm
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
i2c_hid                20480  0
i2c_piix4              24576  0
input_polldev          16384  1 lis3lv02d
ip6table_filter        16384  0
ip6_tables             24576  1 ip6table_filter
iptable_filter         16384  1
ip_tables              24576  1 iptable_filter
ipt_REJECT             16384  3
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
iwlmvm                266240  0
iwlwifi               147456  1 iwlmvm
jbd2                   90112  1 ext4
joydev                 20480  0
k10temp                16384  0
kvm                   495616  1 kvm_amd
kvm_amd                69632  0
libahci                28672  1 ahci
libata                204800  2 ahci,libahci
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
lp                     20480  0
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
mac80211              569344  1 iwlmvm
mbcache                16384  2 ext4
mfd_core               16384  1 rtsx_pci
mmc_core              118784  1 rtsx_pci_sdmmc
msr                    16384  0
nf_conntrack           90112  2 nf_conntrack_ipv4,xt_conntrack
nf_conntrack_ipv4      20480  2
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_reject_ipv4         16384  1 ipt_REJECT
nls_cp437              20480  1
nls_utf8               16384  1
parport                40960  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
parport_pc             28672  0
pci_stub               16384  1
ppdev                  20480  0
processor              36864  4
psmouse                40960  0
rfkill                 20480  4 cfg80211
rtsx_pci               49152  1 rtsx_pci_sdmmc
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
scsi_mod              188416  3 sd_mod,libata,sg
sd_mod                 40960  4
serio_raw              16384  0
sg                     32768  0
shpchp                 32768  0
snd                    73728  18 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
snd_hda_codec         102400  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_generic    65536  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45056  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    69632  1
snd_hda_core           61440  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          32768  5
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                86016  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_timer              28672  1 snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
sp5100_tco             16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  0
sunrpc                274432  1
thermal                20480  0
tpm                    36864  2 tpm_tis,tpm_tis_core
tpm_tis                16384  0
tpm_tis_core           20480  1 tpm_tis
ttm                    81920  1 amdgpu
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
usbcore               208896  5 usbhid,ehci_hcd,xhci_pci,xhci_hcd,ehci_pci
usbhid                 49152  0
vboxdrv               380928  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxpci                24576  0
vfat                   20480  1
xhci_hcd              167936  1 xhci_pci
xhci_pci               16384  0
x_tables               28672  7 ipt_REJECT,ip_tables,iptable_filter,xt_tcpudp,ip6table_filter,xt_conntrack,ip6_tables
xt_conntrack           16384  2
xt_tcpudp              16384  2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed,

I went back to a kernel with a custom DSDT override, this enabled the cpu frequency.